# nsIFind has aWordBreaker functionality

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to use the nsIFind function and on opening it in MXR I see that it has something called aWordBreaker.

I'm looking for help on how to set aWordBreaker and learn how it behaves.

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/embedding/components/find/src/nsFind.cpp#543

I'm trying to learn about this and how to use it, but need some help.

If I do this:

```
   let finder = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/rangefind;1"]
                  .createInstance()
                  .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFind);

   console.log('finder',finder);
```

I find that finder has this:

```
Find: function
QueryInterface: Function
caseSensitive: false
findBackwards: false
```

So I can set finder.caseSensitive but I can't set finder.aWordBreaker.

So in summary: I'm looking for help on how to set aWordBreaker and learn how it behaves.

Useful sources on MXR:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/intl/lwbrk/public/nsIWordBreaker.h
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/intl/lwbrk/src/nsSampleWordBreaker.cpp

Example usage here:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/editor/txtsvc/src/nsTextServicesDocument.cpp#3646

```
3645   nsIWordBreaker* wordBreaker = nsContentUtils::WordBreaker();
3646   nsWordRange res = wordBreaker->FindWord(str, strLen, strOffset);
```

Does anyone know how to get access to nsContentUtils with javascript?